# Opening File Directory by using a button

Tags: python, directory

Hi i am trying to do a simple program for my school project, this is the first time i am using python as i am used to c# programming

I am using Window7, Is there ways in which I can press a button in a TK GUI and this directory be pop out ?

```
InitDir = "C:\AgmPlots"
```

Comment: What is "pop out" supposed to mean?

Comment: try tkFileDialog.askdirectory()

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams to open directory folder

Comment: In Word? On another computer's display?

Comment: Hi @glasslion TkFileDialog.askdirectory() is simplify just asking for the directory.. not opening up the specific directory.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams means that it just open a specific folder in my computer... Open "C:\Program Files". Not execute any program just open the directory

Comment: How would you do it in C# then. Just to understand the "opening up" bit.

Comment: Uh... you *must* open it in a specific program. How else do you expect to be able to display it?

Comment: @ZhenHui -- No matter what, you're using a program to "open" the directory.  On windows, the program might be windows explorer (do they still use that?).  On OS-X it's finder -- On Linux it's something else depending on your desktop environment.

Comment: @Hyperboreus bascially you just click on the button and the directory is opened.. private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      System.IO.StreamReader sr = new 
         System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
      MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
      sr.Close();
   }
}

Comment: @ZhenHui So you want a message box with the content of a file?

Comment: @Hyperboreus That is in C#.. i need it in python, to click on a button to open the specific folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other stated, you need some (platform specific) program to "open" a directory.

The most platform-independent way could possibly be the `webbrowser` module. (Although it has `web` in its name, it opens my standard file manager with `file://` URLs).

```
import webbrowser
```

And somewhere inside your event handler:

```
webbrowser.open ('file:///home/nobody') #your path here
```

Comment: NICE thank you this is exactly what i want, @Hyperboreus is there ways in which i can implement this function into a button as i still have other function to add in too.

Comment: As I said, put this into the event handler of your button.